# Add a variable depending on how many times it is used in Foreach

Tags: php

First of all... I will provide you with my code:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT reference, price FROM ps_product_attribute WHERE id_product = ". implode(' AND ', $_POST['checkbox']) ."");
    $stmt1->execute();
    $product = $stmt1->fetchAll();

    // Get Product Price
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = ". implode(' AND ', $_POST['checkbox']) ."");
    $stmt2->execute();
    $productPrice = $stmt2->fetchAll();

    foreach ($productPrice as $rowPrice) {
        foreach ($product as $row) {
            $Price = $rowPrice['price'] + $row['price'];
            $NET = $Price;
            $VAT = $Price * 0.2;
            $Total = $Price + $VAT;

            print '<tr>';
                print '<td>'. $row['reference'] .'</td>';
                print '<td>Product Name</td>';
                print '<td>'. $quantity .'</td>';
                print '<td>&pound;'. number_format((float)$Price, 2, '.', '') .'</td>';
            print '</tr>';
        }
    }

    echo '
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 0;"></td>
            <td style="border: 0;"></td>
            <td><p style="font-weight: bold; float: right;">NET Amount</p></td>
            <td><p style="float: right;">&pound;'. number_format((float)$NET, 2, '.', '') .'</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 0;"></td>
            <td style="border: 0;"></td>
            <td><p style="font-weight: bold; float: right;">VAT</p></td>
            <td><p style="float: right;">&pound;'. number_format((float)$VAT, 2, '.', '') .'</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 0;"></td>
            <td style="border: 0;"></td>
            <td><p style="font-weight: bold; float: right;">Total</p></td>
            <td><p style="float: right;">&pound;'. number_format((float)$Total, 2, '.', '') .'</p></td>
        </tr>
    ';
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

I am trying to make the variable $NET be equal to however many rows are returned with a price. For example, if the id_product is 8 it will return two products £18.95 and £21.00. Currently $NET is set at £21.00 but it should be £39.95.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statements do not look correct - if `$_POST['checkbox']` is an array with multiple items the resultant sql would fail to be prepared properly I think.

As an example, consider the following:

```
$_POST['checkbox']=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$stmt2 = "SELECT * FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = ". implode(' AND ', $_POST['checkbox'] );
echo $stmt2;
```

This would generate sql like:

```
SELECT * FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5 AND 6 AND 7 AND 8 AND 9
```

However, if you were to use the `IN` operator you could structure your sql as follows:

```
$_POST['checkbox']=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$stmt2 = "SELECT * FROM ps_product WHERE id_product IN ( " . implode( ',', $_POST['checkbox'] ) ." );";
echo $stmt2;
```

Which would generate sql like:

```
SELECT * FROM ps_product WHERE id_product IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 );
```

But because you are using two tables that are related you could probably join the tables and make a single query.

```
$sql="select * from `ps_products` p
    left outer join `ps_product_attribute` a on a.`product_id`=p.`product_id`
    where p.`product_id` in (".implode(',',$_POST['checkbox']).");";
```

Which should then make the end loop easier to work with ( though I might have missed something here ) and you could probably use a loop like this:

```
$TOTAL=0;$NET=0;
while( $rs = $stmt1->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJECT ) ){
    $price = $rs->price;
    $VAT = $price * 0.2;
    $NET += $price;
    $TOTAL += ( $price + $VAT );
    /* other stuff */
}
```